# Not able to boot off of bootable USB for Windows 10 (made on Arch Linux)

Tags: windows, boot, usb

I've been following instructions on [this website](http://onetransistor.blogspot.com/2014/09/make-bootable-windows-usb-from-ubuntu.html) to get a bootable USB of Windows 10 so I can install it on another computer. This is essentially what I have done:

1. Used GParted to create a brand new `msdos` partition table on the USB (filesystem FAT32)
2. Used `dd` to copy over all the contents of the Windows 10 ISO to the USB

   Contents: boot/ , efi/ , sources/ , support/ , autorun.inf, bootmgr, bootmgr.efi, setup.exe
3. Changed the boot order on the machine to boot from USB first
4. Just a flashing cursor on a black screen appears, unable to boot

Any idea as to why this could be happening? All my systems are 64-bit, and many websites said to make sure there is a file called "efi/boot/bootx64.efi" because that
is needed for booting up, and there is on the USB drive.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is with your step 2. You should not use `dd` to copy files because it will modify USB filesystem structure.

After you format USB drive to FAT32, copy Windows files using any file manager. That's all you need to make a bootable USB drive from UEFI (provided that Windows supports UEFI, and Windows 10 certainly does).